# Android SyncAdapter doesn't syncs on my device Samsung S6 Edge Plus Nougat(syncs periodically on API<=23)

Tags: android, android-service, android-syncadapter

I have a problem using my SyncAdapter. The weirdest thing about it, is it was working earlier, but now sync only works if i call it manually.

It also not works on emulator (API 24)

Here is my code of the sync adapter:

```
 public class SmogAppSyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {

private static final String LOG_TAG = SmogAppSyncAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

public static final int SYNC_INTERVAL =  60; // 60 * 60 = 1h to the nearest 20min.
public static final int SYNC_FLEXTIME = SYNC_INTERVAL / 3;
public static final int POLLUTION_DISTANCE = 10000; //preferred distance between prefs location and nearest measurement point
private static final int POLLUTION_NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;

private ContentResolver mContentResolver;
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private Context syncContext;
private int prefsPollutionLevel;
private double prefsHomeLocationLatitude;
private double prefsHomeLocationLongitude;
private boolean prefsNewMessageNotification;
private int currentApiPollutionLevel;
private Float currentApiPollutionLevelLatitude;
private Float currentApiPollutionLevelLongitude;


/**
 * Set up the sync adapter
 */
SmogAppSyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
    super(context, autoInitialize);
    /*
     * If your app uses a content resolver, get an instance of it
     * from the incoming Context
     */
    mContentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    syncContext = context;
    prefsHomeLocationLatitude = prefs.getFloat(syncContext.getResources().getString(R.string.pref_key_home_latitude), 0f);
    prefsHomeLocationLongitude = prefs.getFloat(syncContext.getResources().getString(R.string.pref_key_home_longitude), 0f);
    prefsNewMessageNotification = prefs.getBoolean(syncContext.getResources().getString(R.string.pref_key_notification_new_message), true);
    prefsPollutionLevel = Integer.valueOf(prefs.getString(syncContext.getResources().getString(R.string.pref_key_pollution_level_list), "0"));
}

@Override
public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {

    // fetching remote data and insert some stuff

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onPerformSync was called");

}

/**
 * Helper method to schedule the sync adapter periodic execution
 */
private static void configurePeriodicSync(Context context, int syncInterval, int flexTime) {
    Account account = getSyncAccount(context);
    String authority = context.getString(R.string.content_authority);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
      //   we can enable inexact timers in our periodic sync
        SyncRequest request = new SyncRequest.Builder().
                syncPeriodic(syncInterval, flexTime).
                setSyncAdapter(account, authority).
                setExtras(new Bundle()).build();
        ContentResolver.requestSync(request);
    } else {
    ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account,
            authority, new Bundle(), syncInterval);
    }
}

/**
 * Helper method to have the sync adapter sync immediately
 *
 * @param context The context used to access the account service
 */
private static void syncImmediately(Context context) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
    bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
    ContentResolver.requestSync(getSyncAccount(context),
            context.getString(R.string.content_authority), bundle);
}

/**
 * Helper method to get the fake account to be used with SyncAdapter, or make a new one
 * if the fake account doesn't exist yet.  If we make a new account, we call the
 * onAccountCreated method so we can initialize things.
 *
 * @param context The context used to access the account service
 * @return a fake account.
 */
public static Account getSyncAccount(Context context) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getSyncAccount");
    // Get an instance of the Android account manager
    AccountManager accountManager =
            (AccountManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE);

    // Create the account type and default account
    Account newAccount = new Account(
            context.getString(R.string.app_name), context.getString(R.string.sync_account_type));

    // If the password doesn't exist, the account doesn't exist
    if (null == accountManager.getPassword(newAccount)) {

    /*
     * Add the account and account type, no password or user data
     * If successful, return the Account object, otherwise report an error.
     */
        if (!accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(newAccount, "", null)) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "return null");
            return null;
        }
        /*
         * If you don't set android:syncable="true" in
         * in your <provider> element in the manifest,
         * then call ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, AUTHORITY, 1)
         * here.
         */

        onAccountCreated(newAccount, context);
    }
    else {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "If the password doesn't exist, the account doesn't exist");
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Account name: " + newAccount.name);
    return newAccount;
}

private static void onAccountCreated(Account newAccount, Context context) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAccountCreated");
    /*
     * Since we've created an account
     */
    SmogAppSyncAdapter.configurePeriodicSync(context, SYNC_INTERVAL, SYNC_FLEXTIME);

    /*
     * Without calling setSyncAutomatically, our periodic sync will not be enabled.
     */
    ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(newAccount, context.getString(R.string.content_authority), 1);
    ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(newAccount, context.getString(R.string.content_authority), true);

    /*
     * Finally, let's do a sync to get things started
     */
  //  syncImmediately(context);
}

public static void initializeSyncAdapter(Context context) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "inside initializeSyncAdapter");
    getSyncAccount(context);
}
```

}

My service:

```
public class SmogAppSyncService extends Service {

private static SmogAppSyncAdapter sSyncAdapter = null;
private static final Object sSyncAdapterLock = new Object();


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    synchronized (sSyncAdapterLock) {
        sSyncAdapter = new SmogAppSyncAdapter(getApplicationContext(), true);
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return sSyncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
}
```

}

In my manifest i added those:

```
 <service android:name=".services.sync.SmogAppAuthenticatorService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
            android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".services.sync.SmogAppSyncService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":sync">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
    </service>
```

and permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Here are my other xml files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:contentAuthority="@string/content_authority"
android:accountType="@string/sync_account_type"
android:userVisible="false"
android:supportsUploading="false"
android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
android:isAlwaysSyncable="true" />
```

Authetnicator.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accountType="@string/sync_account_type"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:smallIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

I can provide more details, if it will be helpful. I really stuck with this problem and checked some answers in stackoverflow. Doesn't really helped me. Is any way to get this work? The periodic sync works on emulator but not on real device.

UPDATE: I've read about Doze Mode which could be the cause, but it is rather not in my case or i've just configured something wrong. 
Basically Doze Mode with its battery optimalization can disable some background tasks on device.

Comment: What's the brand of your real device? I've encountered problems like this in Xiaomi devices.

Comment: My device is samsung galaxy 6 edge plus, it was working previously, but not now

Comment: I find out, that the problem occurs only on my phone so far, i have Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge Plus with Android Nougat version

Comment: It is not occur in API 19

Comment: Hi. Looks like I am having the same issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44405585/syncadapters-periodic-syncs-abandonned

Comment: @okset Vasily's answer isn't correct in my case, as I have a periodic sync set to 4 hours.

Answer (score 15):

From `SyncRequest.Builder#syncPeriodic(long, long)` javadoc:

```
 /**
     * Build a periodic sync.
     ...
     * @param pollFrequency the amount of time in seconds that you wish
     *            to elapse between periodic syncs. A minimum period of 1 hour is enforced.
     ...
     */
    public Builder syncPeriodic(long pollFrequency, long beforeSeconds) {
        ...
    }
```

Note that it states that a minimum periodic sync timeout of 1 hour is enforced. That's probably your issue.

But since when? I haven't heard of such a long timeout before. Let's dig into it.

I ran the following commands:

```
$ cd ~/aosp/frameworks/base
$ find ./ -name SyncRequest.java | xargs git blame | grep "A minimum period of 1 hour is enforced"
```

And get this result:

```
e96c3b7eff52 (Shreyas Basarge  2016-01-29 19:25:51 +0000 310)          *            to elapse between periodic syncs. A minimum period of 1 hour is enforced.
```

Looks like the commit is from January 2016. This explains why it works on API 19 but not on 25.

I further verified that this commit added the code that increased the minimum timeout from 60 seconds to 1 hour.

And then you might ask why on earth would Google devs change the semantics of working API on which many apps rely without a proper notification to developers? And the answer is as usual - because they can.

Comment: Unfortunately the issue is still ocurring, even when i change the sync period to 1.5h.